# Upload file to a server using php

Tags: php, angular, laravel, file, upload

Very good, nice to greet you,

I have a project with Angula, Laravel and Bootstrap, I am creating a form to be able to upload files through the project's website to the server, I have put this code below and it doesn't work correctly, could you help me by telling me the code that do I have to put or tell me where am I failing?

Awaiting your answers, receive a cordial greeting,

Thank you very much,

This is in my HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <form method="post" action="test_act.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div>
        <span>Choose file</span>  
           <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"><br/>
              <input type="submit" name="fupload" id="fupload">
       </div> 
     </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

test_act.php

```
<?php 
include ("test_cls.php");
if(isset($_POST['fupload']))
{
    $dirpath="upload";
    $uploader   =   new Uploader();

    $uploader->setExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','png','gif','doc','docx', 'pdf'));  //allowed extensions list//

    $uploader->setMaxSize(1);                          //set max file size to be allowed in MB//

    $uploader->setDir($dirpath);

    if($uploader->uploadFile('fileToUpload'))          //txtFile is the filebrowse element name //
    {   
        $suc_file  =   $uploader->getUploadName(); //get uploaded file name, renames on upload//
        echo $suc_file." successfully uploaded";
    }
    else                    //upload failed
        echo $uploader->getMessage(); //get upload error message
}
?>
```

test_cls.php (Upload Class)

```
<?php
class Uploader
{
    private $destinationPath;
    private $errorMessage;
    private $extensions;
    private $maxSize;
    private $uploadName;
    public $name='Uploader';

    function setDir($path){
        $this->destinationPath  =   $path;
    }

    function setMaxSize($sizeMB){
        $this->maxSize  =   $sizeMB * (1024*1024);
    }

    function setExtensions($options){
        $this->extensions   =   $options;
    }

    function setMessage($message){
        $this->errorMessage =   $message;
    }

    function getMessage(){
        return $this->errorMessage;
    }

    function getUploadName(){
        return $this->uploadName;
    }

    function uploadFile($fileBrowse){
        $result =   false;
        $size   =   $_FILES[$fileBrowse]["size"];
        $name   =   $_FILES[$fileBrowse]["name"];
        $ext    =   pathinfo($name,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        $this->uploadName=  $name;

        if(empty($name))
        {
            $this->setMessage("File not selected ");
        }
        else if($size>$this->maxSize)
        {
            $this->setMessage("Too large file !");
        }
        else if(in_array($ext,$this->extensions))
        {
            if(!is_dir($this->destinationPath))
                mkdir($this->destinationPath);
            if(!is_dir($this->destinationPath.'/'.$ext))
                mkdir($this->destinationPath.'/'.$ext);

            if(file_exists($this->destinationPath.'/'.$ext.'/'.$this->uploadName))
                $this->setMessage("File already exists. !");
            else if(!is_writable($this->destinationPath.'/'.$ext))
                $this->setMessage("Destination is not writable !");
            else
            {
                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$fileBrowse]["tmp_name"],$this->destinationPath.'/'.$ext.'/'.$this->uploadName))
                {
                    $result =   true;
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->setMessage("Upload failed , try later !");
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $this->setMessage("Invalid file format !");
        }
        return $result;
    }

    function deleteUploaded($fileBrowse){
        $name   =   $_FILES[$fileBrowse]["name"];
        $ext    =   pathinfo($name,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        unlink($this->destinationPath.'/'.$ext.'/'.$this->uploadName);
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine.

However, you might check :

- is upload directory created
- does upload directory have the needed rights
- your file is not exceeding upload limit size defined php.ini

Comment: Hello, happy to greet you, and thank you for your quick response,

I have tested the permissions are fine, the php.ini is at 10MB for which I understand that it is correct, by default I only have the creation of the upload folder on the server, where do I have to create the upload folder on the server?

Awaiting your reply, receive a cordial greeting,

Thank you very much,

Comment: Hi. My pleasure. It is not because the current user has required rights that www-data user (if you use Apahce) has. Be careful ! What is your developement environnement (PHP version, OS, ...) ?

Comment: Hey @Aaron_Actu I was trying to debug the submit button, and I noticed that it doesn't execute any of the code. I do not know why, I will try to find a solution but if you can give me a hand it would be of great help.

Comment: Weird. May you send us a picture of the directory where the code is ?